# disruptor event visability

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern

I am doing a prototype of creating a actor model on top of the Disruptor (https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/wiki).  Based off all the examples, mutation of a event doesn't use volatile or any other way to make sure visibility is preserved.  I am wondering what allows this to be safe?

In the FAQ, it sounds like this is taken care of (https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#do-you-relax-the-consistency-model-to-gain-performance) but I have yet to see how.

Thanks for your time reading this!

Answer (score 0):

The gory details are in Sequencers: [SingleProducerSequencer](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lmax/disruptor/SingleProducerSequencer.java) & [MultiProducerSequencer](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lmax/disruptor/MultiProducerSequencer.java)

There are several blog posts about it as well referenced from the [disruptor wiki](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/wiki/Blogs-And-Articles#why-the-disruptor-is-so-fast)

Comment: Thanks. Read the tech paper today and I think I get most of it.